# Finding time complexity of the minimal element in hash table?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, hash-function, data-structure, analysis-of-algorithms

I want to understand and solve the next task: If we draw elements from a universal set `U` and insert `n` (different) elements into an empty hash table `T` of length `m` , for `m = O(n)` , what is the time complexity of finding the minimal element in a `T`?

I would say linear because we have 0 elements and as the input grows, the algorithm takes proportionally longer to complete. But algorithm with this time complexity will process the input `(n)` in `“n”` number of operations. If I'm correct, what happens when the number of elements and length isn't the same, since we have `n` different elements and `m` length which is equal to `O(n)`?

Comment: Hash tables aren't sorted so you are correct. It would take $O(n)$ time to find the minimal or maximal element.

Comment: @JohnDouma, I encourage you to write that as an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted.  The site discourages writing answers in a comment.

Comment: @D.W. I appreciate what you are saying but my comment is not really a complete answer. Kollleey must still provide the details to prove that finding a minimal element in a hash table is $O(n)$.